# How to extend my washing machine standpipe?

Tags: plumbing, drain, washing-machine, plumbing-fixture, clothes-washer

I need to extend my standpipe so that it's higher than my washing machine drum height.

I need it to be about 24" taller than it currently is. I'm not experienced doing any plumbing work beyond installing a new shower head.

I've included photos of the current state of my standpipe.

I'm renting an apartment, so I'd prefer a solution that could be reversible if needed.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Comment: Why do you think this is a necessary change?

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo because everything I've read says that my standpipe opening needs to be above my washing machine drum height and it currently is below it.

Comment: It needs to be high enough not to build up some velocity on the way down, or it risks backing up. It needs to be high enough not to syphon out the drum unintentionally. Beyond that, it it works ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be easy. Start by figuring out how much additional height you need. Use a pipe wrench to loosen the faceted collar at the top of the trap, and the standpipe should just pull up and out of that fitting. Take it to a store and tell them you need a piece the same size but however-much longer. You may have to get something a bit longer than that and have the store cut it down, or use a hacksaw to cut it down yourself. Slide the new pipe into place, and use the wrench to tighten the collar of the slip-joint again to seal the connection.

(Depending on how it goes, you may need to repack the slip-joint to get a good seal. That isn't difficult either -- remove the ring entirely, wrap some rope packing around the pipe just above the junction (or install a new packing washer, depending on the age of the hardware), slip the ring back over the tube and tighten it onto the threads; doing so compresses the packing and makes the joint waterproof.)

Answer (score 3):

@keshlam's [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/44914/14510) is the proper way to go about it, but might be more permanent than it needs to be.

An easier and cheaper approach would be to slip an extension tube inside the existing standpipe.  From the photo, it is not clear if that is 2 inch or 1.5 inch pipe.  Look for an extension pipe of 1.5 or 1.25 inches, respectively, to slide inside it and secure.  For a full 24 inches, you could use two of [these](http://www.homedepot.com/p/DBHL-1-1-2-in-x-12-in-PVC-Tailpiece-Extension-HP9793A/100346686):

[image]

Those will easily couple to each other, but you'll have to do something to keep the lower piece from sliding down like duct tape or tying it to a shelf or hook in the wall.

The dynamics of the situation don't call for the connection to be water tight unless the lower pipe is prone to backing up.